# Chrome Devtool : I got error but most of them in null file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js, frontend

i'm using Vue js ,but this issue very annoying .
i can't see where the error is, and even when i set debugger i can't debug it shows an empty file.
please check the image .
if anyone can help me what is the reason ?

[image: 1]

Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: please! share you code

Comment: Why tagged angular and react?

Comment: As you can see under the `modules` error, the component name that throws the error is `DefaultCard`. The second error `AsyncComponent` refers to the `AsynComponentWrapper` or `ExternalDashboard`.

Comment: Because the error maybe not only for vue , i don't know. @Jai

Comment: Yeah, I know, but what is the reason to be in a null file, even if I put a debugger in my code it's taken me to an empty file in runtime and I can't debug anything.@Amini

Answer (score 0):

The Reason Was From Vite HMR .